# Curly bracket sets and sorting in python 3.2

Tags: python, sorting, brackets

Hi I have two questions:

1. I am trying to build sets of two using i.e. of the form example: `new = [{24,33},{12,13},{17,19},....]`. Basically I have data in the form of two lists say one is called `N = [24,12,17,....]` and the other is `z = [33,13,19,....]`. I have been trying to achieve this using:

   ```
   new=[]
   for i in range(len(z)):
       new.append({z[i]})
       new.extend({N[i]})
   print(new)
   ```

   and have tried many variations of append and extend with or without curly brackets.
2. Once 1) is achieved I would then like to rearrange new according to the size of the second item in each set, that is in ascending order of z, so I would like to get:

   ```
   new=[{12,13},{17,19},{24,33}]
   ```

Comment: 2) sets are unordered so there's no such thing as a "second item".

Comment: Do you actually need to create sets, where the items are unique and unordered, or do you needs lists where the items don't have to be unique and they have order?

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip()` to pair two lists:

```
new = [{a, b} for a, b in zip(N, z)]
```

But sets are *unordered* so there is no 'second value'. You can sort on the minimum value perhaps:

```
new.sort(key=lambda s: min(s))
```

If you need to sort it on the values of `z`, do so before creating your sets:

```
from operator import itemgetter

new = [{a, b} for a, b in sorted(zip(N, z), key=itemgetter(1))]
```

**But** if these are really x, y coordinates, then just use `zip()` and `sorted()` to give you a sequence of *tuples*:

```
new = sorted(zip(N, z), key=itemgetter(1))
```

A `set()` contains only unique values:

```
>>> {1, 1}
set([1])
```

A tuple is an ordered (immutable) sequence instead:

```
>>> (1, 1)
(1, 1)
```

Comment: Note that `map` won't give OP a `list`

Comment: @mgilson: In Python 2 it will. *But* there is a Python 3.2 specification, so I removed it again. :-)

Comment: I don't think the OP really wants sets, apparently they represent coordinates. Probably should be tuples

Comment: @gnibbler I obtain the lists z and N from a calculation, but they are akin to x and y, but since they are two different lists and I want to sort the list in an ascending order w.r.t to z I thought of making the sets first.

Comment: @shokan: Use sets when you want *unique* values. If the paired items from `z` and `N` are *the same*, your set will contain only *1* item.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- *unique* values is only 1 (common) use of sets.  Using the fact that membership tests takes O(1) calculations is another place where they end up being quite useful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I know :).  I just didn't want OP to get the idea that they could use `sets` *only* because they ensure the values are unique.

Comment: @Martin I tried what you suggested but it merely pairs my lists up. Part 2) remains unsolved.

Comment: @shokan: What line from my answer are you using?

Comment: okay this works perfectly:
new = sorted(zip(expn_12, zex_12), key=itemgetter(1))
new.sort()                                                              Thanks everyone!

Comment: @shokan: If you need to sort *again*, then you are sorting on the *first* value, not the second. May as well remove the `key` part then, it is useless in that case and costing you performance because you are throwing away the result of the first sort. Without the `key=` argument the *first* sort is enough.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is easy:

```
new = [set(x) for x in zip(N,z)]
```

The second actually needs to be accomplished *before making the sets* since sets are unordered:

```
new = [set(x) for x in sorted(zip(N,z),key=lambda x:x[1])]
```

or

```
import operator
new = [set(x) for x in sorted(zip(N,z),key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
```

for those who don't like `lambda`

---

It is also uncertain whether you actually want to use `sets` for this.  I think that a `tuple` might be better -- in which case just use the `sorted` step.

```
new = sorted(zip(N,z),key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Sets don't maintain any order and aren't indexible, so they don't make a very good data structure for holding `x-y` pairs as you don't have any way of knowing which element is `x` and which element is `y`

Comment: thanks but actually I want a way to sort them together since the two lists z and N and like x and y values and I do not want to mix them up.

Comment: @shokan -- This won't mix up the pairs.  For each `z`, you'll still get a corresponding `N`

Comment: @shokan: that's what the `sorted()` callable *does*; sort the result of `zip()` as pairs.

Comment: @gnibbler -- itemgetter is nice, and faster than `lambda`, the speed difference is usually not important (unless this is actually in a really tight loop) and `lambda` doesn't involve the additional import.

Comment: although `operator.itemgetter` looks ugly inline. I always `from operator import itemgetter`

Comment: @gnibbler -- Yeah, I do to.  But, for the purpose of the question, I find that it makes it clear where `itemgetter` comes from.  (You can more or less ignore the first line and just read the second in this case)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list(map(set, zip(N, z)))
[{24, 33}, {12, 13}, {17, 19}]
```

> I would then like to rearrange new according to the size of the second item

Sets are unordered, so there is no such thing as a "second item".

If the ordering of the two items is important, you should probably be using tuples rather than sets.

To reorder the tuples according to the magnitude of the second element:

```
>>> sorted(zip(N, z) , key=lambda x:x[1])
[(12, 13), (17, 19), (24, 33)]
```

Comment: `map` won't give OP a list.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want [sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) (where the two values must be distinct, and there's no order), but tuples - simply two items coming one after another.

Use the [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function, and [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort:

```
>>> z = [24, 12, 17]
>>> N = [33, 13, 19]
>>> sorted(zip(z, N), key=lambda tpl: tpl[1])
[(12, 13), (17, 19), (24, 33)]
```